# What is the relationship between seneca and redis

Tags: node.js, npm, redis, seneca

There are two plugins in npm js, one called redis, the other seneca-redis-store, what is the difference between the two of them? 
https://github.com/senecajs/seneca-redis-store
https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#rediscreateclient

Answer (score 1):

> What is the relationship between seneca and redis

Redis is an in-memory data store. Seneca is a microservices toolkit for Node.js. They can be used together like other databases and toolkits but they don't have to.

> There are two plugins in npm js, one called redis, the other seneca-redis-store, what is the difference between the two of them?

The `redis` module is a general Redis driver for Node that can be used in any Node application.

The `seneca-redis-store` is Redis storage layer for Seneca framework, a module written specificaly for using Redis with Seneca.

It is described pretty well here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/seneca-redis-store